# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, nodejs

I keep getting this error message in my browser inspect element console.

2shortenAddress.js:1

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
at shortenAddress (shortenAddress.js:1:55)
at TransactionsCard (Transactions.jsx:27:54)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:18)
at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:20387:20)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22430:16)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4161:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:31)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:7)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:12)
```

react-dom.development.js:18572

```
   The above error occurred in the <TransactionsCard> component:

at TransactionsCard (http://localhost:3000/src/components/Transactions.jsx:24:3)
at div
at div
at div
at Transactions (http://localhost:3000/src/components/Transactions.jsx:142:7)
at div
at App
at TransactionsProvider (http://localhost:3000/src/context/TransactionContext.jsx:31:3)
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18572
react-dom.development.js:26874

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
at shortenAddress (shortenAddress.js:1:55)
at TransactionsCard (Transactions.jsx:27:54)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:18)
at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:20387:20)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22430:16)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27381:14)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:12)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:5)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26390:7)
at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25806:20)
```

Here is my shortenAddress.js script

```
export const shortenAddress = (address) => `${address.slice(0, 5)}...${address.slice(address.length - 4)}`;
```

And my Transactions.jsx script

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { TransactionContext } from "../context/TransactionContext";

import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";
import dummyData from "../utils/dummyData";
import { shortenAddress } from "../utils/shortenAddress";

const TransactionsCard = ({ addressTo, addressFrom, timestamp, message, keyword, amount, url }) => {
  const gifUrl = useFetch({ keyword });

  return (
    <div className="bg-[#181918] m-4 flex flex-1
      2xl:min-w-[450px]
      2xl:max-w-[500px]
      sm:min-w-[270px]
      sm:max-w-[300px]
      min-w-full
      flex-col p-3 rounded-md hover:shadow-2xl"
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-full mt-3">
        <div className="display-flex justify-start w-full mb-6 p-2">
          <a href={`https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/${addressFrom}`} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
            <p className="text-white text-base">From: {shortenAddress(addressFrom)}</p>
          </a>
          <a href={`https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/${addressTo}`} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
            <p className="text-white text-base">To: {shortenAddress(addressTo)}</p>
          </a>
          <p className="text-white text-base">Amount: {amount} ETH</p>
          {message && (
            <>
              <br />
              <p className="text-white text-base">Message: {message}</p>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        <img
          src={gifUrl || url}
          alt="nature"
          className="w-full h-64 2xl:h-96 rounded-md shadow-lg object-cover"
        />
        <div className="bg-black p-3 px-5 w-max rounded-3xl -mt-5 shadow-2xl">
          <p className="text-[#37c7da] font-bold">{timestamp}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Transactions = () => {
  const { transactions, currentAccount } = useContext(TransactionContext);

  return (
    <div className="flex w-full justify-center items-center 2xl:px-20 gradient-bg-transactions">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:p-12 py-12 px-4">
        {currentAccount ? (
          <h3 className="text-white text-3xl text-center my-2">
            Latest Transactions
          </h3>
        ) : (
          <h3 className="text-white text-3xl text-center my-2">
            Connect your account to see the latest transactions on the block chain
          </h3>
        )}

        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center mt-10">
          {[...dummyData, ...transactions].reverse().map((transaction, i) => (
            <TransactionsCard key={i} {...transaction} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Transactions;
```

[image: A screenshot of what I keep getting on my browser]